# When is a modified web address not suspicious?

Tags: url

I know that there are scam sites that will pose as a real site, but will have a slightly modified address.

For example, "svpervser" or "g00gle" would raise a red flag if they were claiming to actually be Superuser or Google.

But what about something like "https://new.adblockplus.org" when the normal address is "https://adblockplus.org"? So it is basically the same address barring some pre-pended word and a dot?

I once launched Firefox and had a tab open at startup to tell me something like 'you have been using AdBlock for some time, please consider donating' but the URL had that 'new dot' prepended which raised a question mark.

(and yes I do have the addon installed)

Comment: You do understand that `new.adblockplus.org` is a subdomain of `adblockplus.org`, right?  Which means only the owner of `adblockplus.org` controls that particular subdomain.  The URl you describe was an legit adblockplus.org website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of a domain name can have about any subdomain(s).

`example.com` can have `any.thing.example.com`.

If an URL is suspicious or not is subjectively based on opinion.

Many websites allow their users to have their own web space with a subdomain as their URL. An example of this would be a blog platform. E.g. `techhorse.wordpress.com`. Depending on what services the website provides, some users may be able to host malicious content on that subdomain.

Some websites allowing users to host their own content (for example an online form submission service) are frequently subjected to users attempting phishing attacks. E.g. `microsoft.com/forms/random-evil-user/234` acting as a fake login screen.

I'd say you cannot trust a website just because its URL doesn't look suspicious. You'd need to know what kind of website and what services they provide to the public to be sure if an evil user would be able to host their own content.

Comment: To clarify I was wondering simply about when a modified version of a web address is, in and of itself, a cause for suspicion. So it seems that "any.thing.example.com" can always be safely assumed to be an official subdomain of "example.com". But as you point out, a subdomain can be dodgy for other reasons. That's my que answered thank you.

Comment: @TechHorse yeah, exactly! At least that's my opinion on the matter. You might get another answer from someone else, and it could also depend on what domain it relates to.